# Testing a read only textbox with Selenium

Tags: python, unit-testing, selenium

[image]

I would like to test that this textbox is read-only (not able to type/edit). Note: the value in the textbox is different every time.

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="system_lan1_mac" value="00:15:8b:00:5f:8e" disabled="">
```

I have tried to locate the textbox using the following code:

```
    def test_a(self):
        ip = self.find_by_id('system_lan2_mac')
        self.assertFalse(ip.is_enabled())
```

This does not work - I am aware that is_enabled() isn't supposed to be used in this context. There is a timeout error when looking for the textbox. If I change the ID to that of a regular textbox, the test can locate it. As soon as I change it to a read-only ID, there is a timeout error.

Thanks

EDIT: 
find_by_id code:

```
   def find_by_id(self, setting):
    element = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, setting)))
    return element
```

WebDriverWait definition:

> ```
>     cls.wait = WebDriverWait(cls.driver, 10)
> ```

Comment: Your selector uses `id="system_lan2_mac"` while in provided `HTML` it is `id="system_lan1_mac"`... `is_enabled()` could be used in this context

Comment: Hi. Apologies - there is also a system_lan2_mac and the code is not working for that box.

Comment: Do you use `WebdriverWait` + `ExpectedConditions` in your `self.find_by_id()`? If so, show us this code

Comment: @Andersson added to bottom of question post

Comment: Now I think about it...the element_to_be_clickable within find_by_id is probably the cause of the issue...? Since a read-only field can't be clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your expected condition: you're waiting until disabled input field becomes clickable... This won't be `True` in any case. You should try to define your `self.find_by_id()` as below:

```
def find_by_id(self, setting):
    element = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, setting)))
    return element
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to write a test that uses **sendkeys()** and check that the value attribute of the **textbox** has not been changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that - the issue is that I cannot locate the textbox, so I can't send any keys to it anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `disabled` attribute, it is a boolean attribute. If it's present your `<input>` field should be disabled.

As @Andersson said, `assert element.get_attribute('disabled')` would be a way to check it in python.

Comment: This won't works because 1. In current case there is no `class` that contains `"disabled"`, but a `disabled` attribute instead. 2. This syntax is not supported by `Python`... However, your point could be applied as `assert element.get_attribute('disabled')`

Comment: Tnx, you're right, I posted this code without looking based on my case where disabled was actually one of the classes, my mistake.